# why does vmop(Java GC Options) increase when traffic is higher

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

I have a online service with Java. If qps is about 2000, the latency is normal, but if qps is increased to 3000, the latency is much higher.

Is there any advice about the improvement, especially about the STW time?

Code logic is simple(as access service):

1. Decoding Tcp request and Protobuf (about 200KB per request)
2. Splitting request and re-wrap protobuf
3. Routing to backward service and waiting for response asynchronously
4. Handling response from backward service, wrapping with another protobuf and responding to client.

JINFO:

```
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Xmx6g -Xms6g -Xmn4g 
-Djava.ext.dirs=./lib:/data/home/soft/jdk1.8.0_65/jre/lib/ext 
-Dlog4j.configuration=./conf/log4j.properties -Dio.netty.noPreferDirect=false 
-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=4g -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:ParallelCMSThreads=8 
-XX:+CMSScavengeBeforeRemark 
-XX:+PrintSafepointStatistics -XX:PrintSafepointStatisticsCount=1 
-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=./bin/stop.sh -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError 
-XX:HeapDumpPath=. -XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime 
-XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCDetails 
-Xloggc:logs/gc.log -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled 
-XX:ParallelGCThreads=32
```

I have found out the higher STW is caused by vmop. And NO FULL GC occurred during testing.

```
998.860: GenCollectForAllocation          [     253          2              2    ]      [     0     0     0     0     6    ]  0   
         vmop                    [threads: total initially_running wait_to_block]    [time: spin block sync cleanup vmop] page_trap_count
999.578: GenCollectForAllocation          [     253          2              2    ]      [     0     0     0     0    16    ]  0   
         vmop                    [threads: total initially_running wait_to_block]    [time: spin block sync cleanup vmop] page_trap_count
1000.273: GenCollectForAllocation          [     253          3              3    ]      [     0     0     0     0    11    ]  0   
         vmop                    [threads: total initially_running wait_to_block]    [time: spin block sync cleanup vmop] page_trap_count
1000.970: GenCollectForAllocation          [     253          2              2    ]      [     0     0     0     0     8    ]  0   
         vmop                    [threads: total initially_running wait_to_block]    [time: spin block sync cleanup vmop] page_trap_count
1001.666: GenCollectForAllocation          [     253          2              2    ]      [     0     0     0     0     7    ]  0
```

- When qps is about 2000, vmop is lower than 10ms normally. `Total time for which application threads were stopped` is lower than 0.010 seconds.
- Qps is about 3000, vmop is higher than 10ms,

My Question is:

1. Is there any advice about the performance improvement, especially about the STW(vmop) time?
2. What causes high vmop? Reaching the safepoints or copying memories?

More test data:
Backward service keeps qps=3000, and I start one/two Java service to make comparison and get the performance gap. 
Latency of backward service is about 6.8ms.
GC logs of one Java process(with qps=3000 for each process):

```
2019-05-16T14:54:56.742+0800: 67083.398: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0104372 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0001939 seconds
2019-05-16T14:54:57.788+0800: 67084.444: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2019-05-16T14:54:57.788+0800: 67084.444: [ParNew: 5054250K->22742K(5662336K), 0.0109608 secs] 5776050K->744839K(7759488K), 0.0111268 secs] [Times: user=0.33 sys=0.01, real=0.02 secs] 
2019-05-16T14:54:57.799+0800: 67084.455: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0122376 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0001943 seconds
2019-05-16T14:54:58.848+0800: 67085.504: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2019-05-16T14:54:58.848+0800: 67085.504: [ParNew: 5055958K->26545K(5662336K), 0.0108330 secs] 5778055K->748938K(7759488K), 0.0109914 secs] [Times: user=0.34 sys=0.00, real=0.02 secs] 
2019-05-16T14:54:58.859+0800: 67085.515: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0121166 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0002086 seconds
2019-05-16T14:54:59.905+0800: 67086.561: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2019-05-16T14:54:59.905+0800: 67086.561: [ParNew: 5059761K->25093K(5662336K), 0.0115089 secs] 5782154K->747784K(7759488K), 0.0116708 secs] [Times: user=0.36 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 
2019-05-16T14:54:59.917+0800: 67086.573: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0127589 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0001810 seconds
2019-05-16T14:55:00.957+0800: 67087.613: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2019-05-16T14:55:00.957+0800: 67087.613: [ParNew: 5058309K->27559K(5662336K), 0.0043041 secs] 5781000K->750551K(7759488K), 0.0044697 secs] [Times: user=0.11 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 
2019-05-16T14:55:00.962+0800: 67087.618: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0055974 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0001974 seconds
2019-05-16T14:55:02.004+0800: 67088.660: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2019-05-16T14:55:02.004+0800: 67088.660: [ParNew: 5060775K->18771K(5662336K), 0.0032344 secs] 5783767K->742062K(7759488K), 0.0033973 secs] [Times: user=0.08 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs]
```

GC logs of two Java processes(with qps=1500 for each process):

```
2019-05-16T14:49:19.774+0800: 66746.430: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0075090 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0001816 seconds
2019-05-16T14:49:21.879+0800: 66748.535: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2019-05-16T14:49:21.879+0800: 66748.535: [ParNew: 5047304K->15661K(5662336K), 0.0070949 secs] 5601138K->569792K(7759488K), 0.0072536 secs] [Times: user=0.19 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2019-05-16T14:49:21.886+0800: 66748.542: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0084102 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0001858 seconds
2019-05-16T14:49:23.977+0800: 66750.633: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2019-05-16T14:49:23.977+0800: 66750.633: [ParNew: 5048877K->10672K(5662336K), 0.0033657 secs] 5603008K->565100K(7759488K), 0.0035116 secs] [Times: user=0.08 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 
2019-05-16T14:49:23.981+0800: 66750.637: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0045580 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0001763 seconds
2019-05-16T14:49:26.090+0800: 66752.746: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2019-05-16T14:49:26.090+0800: 66752.746: [ParNew2019-05-16T14:49:23.981+0800: 66750.637: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0045580 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0001763 seconds
2019-05-16T14:49:26.090+0800: 66752.746: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2019-05-16T14:49:26.090+0800: 66752.746: [ParNew: 5043888K->9061K(5662336K), 0.0036848 secs] 5598316K->563786K(7759488K), 0.0038302 secs] [Times: user=0.08 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs]
```

Comment: If it's an option I'd try to upgrade to more modern jvm version (11, 12; or at least more recent jdk 1.8 release) and see if that reveals any improvement - you could try to use G1 GC, or some new alternatives like ZGC and Shenandoah. 
You may also want to check this discussion: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/mechanical-sympathy/9oeDihc2WiE/Z7uFSvN9DgAJ
Btw. "vmop" is just a shorthand for "VM operation": https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11u/blob/5f01925b80ed851b133ee26fbcb07026ac04149e/src/hotspot/share/runtime/vm_operations.hpp#L39

Comment: @JurajMartinka Thanks for your reply. I tried G1GC, and did not got better performance. I want to know what causes STW for vmop? Scanning safepoints or copy memories?

Comment: You should give us more details about your problem and some numbers.
What's the end-to-end latency? What portion of it is in-process?
How does the ~2000 qps case differ from the ~3000 qps case?
Could you provide relevant parts of GC logs?
The times for `vmop` you have shown are in the range of 6-16 milliseconds which doesn't look that bad but maybe there are other components involved.

Comment: You could also try jClarity's Censum (https://www.jclarity.com/censum/) to give you a hint what might be unusual in your application. It analyzes GC logs and tries to provide actionable insights. They offer a free trial.

Comment: @JurajMartinka I added more test data and GC logs in the description of question. The STW 16ms is too bad in my scenario, because it is a low latency online service.Thanks for your posting.

Comment: If 16ms is a too long pause for you then, I'm afraid, you're out of luck.
In either case, you should definitely update to more modern JDK (11 or 12); then you can experiment with G1 GC (which improved a lot in later releases) or perhaps Shenandoah which might be a good fit for a low-latency service (http://clojure-goes-fast.com/blog/shenandoah-in-production/); or ZGC - but even those collectors have goals stating "at most 10ms pauses in most cases".

Or go and try Azul Zing if that's an option for you.

Comment: @JurajMartinka I tried JDK12. It definitely showed better performance. With JDK8 and CMS, the 99th percentile latency was about 20~30+ms; with JDK12 and G1GC, the 99th latency was 20ms below; and with JDK12 and ZGC, the 99th latency was 15ms below(but not very stable, might rise up to 40+ms sometimes). Thanks for your advise again. I think I would choose two processes with lower traffic in my production environment:D

Comment: Thank you too for reporting the results you got.
It may well be easiest to just throw more hardware at it instead of elaborative tuning.
I guess you could, perhaps, get some improvements from tuning your server's operating system and/or profiling the application and reducing object allocation rates / memory pressure. But again, it depends on how much time do you want to spend with this :).
If you are interested, I think a good talk is "Performance Methodology" by Shipilev & Pepperdine (Part 1: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zw_z7pjis7k , Part 2: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eDTTxYCGsKc)

Answer (score 1):

You have your causality backwards, it is not *caused by* the vmop. The vmop is the safepoint requested by the garbage collector under which it can execute its stop the world tasks.

If you want to analyze GC behavior you need to look at GC logs first before looking at safepoints.

Comment: It is not caused by backwards. I tried to start two processes to balance the traffic, and the performance is OK. As I know, the 'spin' time is caused by reaching the safepoint. What does VM do for the vmop option?
And I turned on JVM options "-XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime -XX:+PrintGCDetails  -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCDetails  -Xloggc:logs/gc.log" to check GC logs, the STW time was the same as vmop.

Comment: You keep referring to the `vmop` option but I'm not aware (and cannot see) any such thing. As I mentioned before, `vmop` seems to be only a shorthand for "VM operation", of which there are many - e.g. `GenCollectForAllocation` in your case.
In this case, the name suggests that JVM runs GC to get some free space to satisfy memory allocation.

Comment: In my understanding, reaching Safepoint is the reason for stopping the world. Why 
 does vmop ``GenCollectForAllocation `` stop the world?

Comment: Because that's the Young Generation collection and all such collection need to "stop the world" (all application threads) to identify garbage and clean that out properly.